# Python, Call a class function within another class

Tags: python, class, call

Can you anyone please help me call the **broadcast function** from  class **BroadcastServerFactory** in **class test**, as per attached code

I have tried so many methods of call a function from another class, but no solution

```
import sys

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File

from autobahn.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory, \
                               WebSocketServerProtocol, \
                               listenWS


class test():
    //call broadcast function from here


class BroadcastServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

   def onOpen(self):
      self.factory.register(self)

   def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
      if not binary:
         self.factory.broadcast("'%s' from %s" % (msg, self.peerstr))

   def connectionLost(self, reason):
      WebSocketServerProtocol.connectionLost(self, reason)
      self.factory.unregister(self)


class BroadcastServerFactory(WebSocketServerFactory):
   """
   Simple broadcast server broadcasting any message it receives to all
   currently connected clients.
   """

   def __init__(self, url, debug = False, debugCodePaths = False):
      WebSocketServerFactory.__init__(self, url, debug = debug, debugCodePaths = debugCodePaths)
      self.clients = []
      self.tickcount = 0
      self.tick()

   def tick(self):
      self.tickcount += 1
      self.broadcast("'tick %d' from server" % self.tickcount)
      reactor.callLater(1, self.tick)

   def register(self, client):
      if not client in self.clients:
         print "registered client " + client.peerstr
         self.clients.append(client)

   def unregister(self, client):
      if client in self.clients:
         print "unregistered client " + client.peerstr
         self.clients.remove(client)

   def broadcast(self, msg):
      print "broadcasting message '%s' .." % msg
      for c in self.clients:
         c.sendMessage(msg)
         print "message sent to " + c.peerstr


if __name__ == '__main__':

   if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'debug':
      log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
      debug = True
   else:
      debug = False

   ServerFactory = BroadcastServerFactory
   #ServerFactory = BroadcastPreparedServerFactory

   factory = ServerFactory("ws://localhost:9000",
                           debug = debug,
                           debugCodePaths = debug)

   factory.protocol = BroadcastServerProtocol
   factory.setProtocolOptions(allowHixie76 = True)
   listenWS(factory)

   webdir = File(".")
   web = Site(webdir)
   reactor.listenTCP(8080, web)

   reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class test():
  def __init__(self, factory):
    factory.broadcast("I don't know what I'm doing!")
```

Meanwhile, in main...

```
factory = ServerFactory("ws://localhost:9000",
  debug = debug,
  debugCodePaths = debug)

test(factory)
```

This will do what you want, but it seems you're missing some core concepts about **classes** and **instances**. For the `test` class to call anything on another class, there needs to be an instance of it first (bar the case of static methods).

Comment: `def __init__(factory):` should be `def __init__(self, factory):`

Comment: thanks

do you mean
BroadcastServerFactory(factory) instead of test(factory)

Comment: No, that would instantiate a new BroadcastServerFactory with the existing one as the URL argument, and you'd get an exception most likely. You want to call broadcast from test right? That's what this does. I think you need to think about what you're actually trying to achieve, and put it in your question.

Comment: all i want t do is to broadcast messages from another class.